# How to include angular material dialog in Authguard in angular6

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material, angular6

I have to restrict to login when user click on button to open angular material multiple dialogs, and I don't know how to do that using Angular authguard.

Comment: problem is not clear. if i'm understand your problem it is possible to open dialog in `AuthGuard` create a material dialog and call open dialog on button click.

Comment: Authguard is used to protect routes and component loading

Answer (score 1):

If the dialog is a separate component,

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    canActivate(route) {
            // check if logged in here
      if(notLoggedIn) {
    this.router.navigate(['/update-password']);
     return false;

        }
return true


    }
```

If not a separate component, then do this

```
// button to open dialog
openDialog() {
 if(notLoggedIn) {
        this.router.navigate(['/update-password']);
         return false;

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guards can make use of observables therefore its enough for you to return an observable which opens a dialog and then passes `true` or `false`.

For example how it's used in my project on `canDeactivate` (guards work on the same principle no matter which case)

```
canDeactivate(
        component: Component,
        currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
        nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        // Opens a modal and returns an observable
        return this.ps.openModal({
            confirmMessage: confirmMessage,
            confirmHeader: confirmHeader,
            modalColor: modalColor,
            approve: approve,
            cancel: cancel,
            buttonsColor: buttonsColor
        });
}
```